Error: connect ETIMEDOUT [DB IP address]:3306 when connecting MYSQL using connection pools
I'm hosting this code on an Azure WebApp and I'm able to connect to the db server when I use a normal connection i.e. open and close connection for every request, but when I use connection pool I get this error:
--inside authoriseUser--
Error occurred while querying database: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT [DB IP address]:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'DB IP address',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}

this is my old code:
    async authoriseUser(memberEmail, context) {
        console.log("--inside authoriseUser--");
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                var authUserStart = performance.now();
                const config = {
                    user: '<username>',
                    password: '<password>',
                    server: '<servername>',
                    database: '<databasename>',
                    options: {
                        encrypt: true,
                        enableArithAbort: true
                    }
                };
                await sql.connect(config);
                const result = await sql.query`SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM tablename WHERE UserID = ${memberEmail}`;
                var authUserEnd = performance.now();
                if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
                    console.log("User found in database");
                    var authUserTime = (authUserEnd - authUserStart) / 1000;
                    console.log("authUserEnd TIme:", authUserTime)
                    resolve(memberEmail);
                } else {
                    console.log("User not found in database");
                    resolve(false);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error occurred while querying database:", error);
                reject(new Error('DatabaseQueryError'));
            } finally {
                await sql.close();
            }
        });
    }

This works, but I feel that it's taking way more time than I could afford and wanted to use connection pools to reduce query time.
This is my code using connection pools:
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const pool = require('./db');

//rest of code

    async authoriseUser(memberEmail, context) {
        console.log("--inside authoriseUser--");
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let connection;
            try {
                var authUserStart = performance.now();
                connection = await pool.getConnection();
                const [rows] = await connection.query('SELECT TOP 1 col1 Table WHERE UserID = ?', [memberEmail]);
                var authUserEnd = performance.now();

                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log("User found in database");
                    var authUserTime = (authUserEnd - authUserStart) / 1000;
                    console.log("authUserEnd Time:", authUserTime);
                    resolve(memberEmail);
                } else {
                    console.log("User not found in database");
                    resolve(false);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error occurred while querying database:", error);
                reject(new Error('DatabaseQueryError'));
            } finally {
                if (connection) connection.release();
            }
        });
    }

db.js:
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '<hostname>',
    user: '<username>',  
    password: '<password>',       
    database: '<databasename>',   
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0,
    connectTimeout: 30000,
  //  ssl: {
  //      rejectUnauthorized: true
  //  }
});

module.exports = pool;


What am I doing wrong? If it's a networking problem I shouldn't be able to connect in either case, but why am I able to connect normally, but not when I use connection pools?

Recently there was a similar question regarding .net and there the problem was with the mysql connector. It was buggy. I suspect this is the case here as well.


Error: connect ETIMEDOUT [DB IP address]:3306 when connecting MYSQL using connection pools

The above error occurs because of MySQL server port 3306 is being blocked by security group rules or server has reached the maximum number of allowed connections. Try with the below code for connecting MySQL using connection pools.
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '<server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com', 
  user: 'admin01', 
  password: '<password>', 
  database: 'db1', 
  port: 3306, 
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: true
  },
  connectionLimit: 10
});

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Connected to the Azure MySQL database.');

  const query = 'SELECT * FROM Tab1'; 

  connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
    connection.release(); 

    if (err) {
      console.error('Error executing query:', err);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Query results:', results);
  });
});

Output:

